# $0<\frac {1}{\sqrt{2+f(x)}+\sqrt{2+g(x)}}<1$ in $C(\mathbb{R}_+)$

Tags: metric-spaces

So let $C(\mathbb{R}_+)$ be all the continuous functions in $[0,\infty)$,

I have the metric space

$(C(\mathbb{R}_+),d) \to (C(\mathbb{R}_+),d)$

I have taken $f,g \in (C(\mathbb{R}_+),d)$

And i want to prove that $0<\frac {1}{\sqrt{2+f(x)}+\sqrt{2+g(x)}}<1$

Question : If not mistaken $f,g \in (C(\mathbb{R}_+),d)$ means that f,g are function with their starting points at $[0,\infty)$ not having a clue about their image/mapping, therefore is there a way to prove the thing I want?

Comment: $f \in C(\Bbb R_+)$ includes that $f: \Bbb R_+ \to \Bbb R_+$.
Does that help to show what you need?

Comment: @Gono that means that every $f:(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ correct?

Comment: I would assume $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ but this depends on your definition of $\Bbb R_+$